# Porqué una Consulta desde java hacia SQL Server no encuentra SELECT MIN en una tabla

Tags: java, select, sql

```
public void consultaAreaTansferido()
{   
    String consulta = null;
    String []Datos= new String [15]; 
    switch (LineaActual())
    {
        case "AOI": 
        consulta= "SELECT * FROM Transferido.AOI WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' AND Recibido = (SELECT MIN(Recibido) from Transferido.AOI) AND Estado = 'Completo'";                        
                 break;
        case "WS":  
        consulta= "SELECT * FROM Transferido.WS WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' AND Recibido = (SELECT MIN(Recibido) from Transferido.WS) AND Estado = 'Completo'";
                 break;
        case "SMT":     
        consulta= "SELECT * FROM Transferido.SMT WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' AND Recibido = (SELECT MIN(Recibido) from Produccion.Transferido)";
                 break;
        case "CC":      
        consulta= "SELECT * FROM Transferido.CC WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' AND Recibido = (SELECT MIN(Recibido) from Produccion.Transferido)";
                 break;
        case "HA":      
        consulta= "SELECT * FROM Transferido.HA WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' AND Recibido = (SELECT MIN(Recibido) from Produccion.Transferido)";
                 break;
        case "HS":      
        consulta= "SELECT * FROM Transferido.HS WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' AND Recibido = (SELECT MIN(Recibido) from Produccion.Transferido)";
                 break;
        case "QA":      
        consulta= "SELECT * FROM Transferido.QA WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' AND Recibido = (SELECT MIN(Recibido) from Produccion.Transferido)";
                 break;
        case "Empaque":   
        consulta= "SELECT * FROM Transferido.EMPAQUE WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' AND Recibido = (SELECT MIN(Recibido) from Produccion.Transferido)";
                 break;
        case "Test":      
        consulta= "SELECT * FROM Transferido.TEST WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' AND Recibido = (SELECT MIN(Recibido) from Produccion.Transferido)";
                 break;
        case "Etiquetas": 
        consulta= "SELECT * FROM Transferido.ETIQUETAS WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' AND Recibido = (SELECT MIN(Recibido) from Produccion.Transferido)";
                 break;
        default: 
                 break;
    } 

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();) 
    {
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(consulta);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Datos[0]=rs.getString("WO");
            Datos[1]=rs.getString("IdProyecto");
            Integer.parseInt(Datos[2]=rs.getString("CantTotal"));
            Datos[3]=rs.getString("AreaEntrega"); //Linea que envia el material
            Datos[4]=rs.getString("AreaRecibe");
            Datos[5]=rs.getString("FechaInicial");
            Datos[6]=rs.getString("FechaFinal");
            Datos[7]=rs.getString("HoraInicial");
            Datos[8]=rs.getString("HoraFinal");
            Integer.parseInt(Datos[9]=rs.getString("Enviado"));
            Integer.parseInt(Datos[10]=rs.getString("Recibido"));
            Integer.parseInt(Datos[11]=rs.getString("Pendiente"));//Pendiente
            Datos[12]=rs.getString("Estado"); //Estado
            Datos[13]=rs.getString("Notas"); //Notas
            Integer.parseInt(Datos[14]=rs.getString("Scrap")); //Scrap
            this.jRadioEnviar.setEnabled(true);
            this.jRadioRecibir.setEnabled(true);
            CantRestanteActual = Entrante-Integer.parseInt(txtCantidad.getText());
        }   
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"<html><body><h1>No se obtuvieron los datos </html></body></h1>"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, es correcto, eso lo entiendo, pero si la tabla unicamente contiene ese unico registro debería devolver ese registro encontrado, cierto? pero no lo hace... solo encuentra el "MIN" cuando en la tabla hay otros registro con la misma llave primaria.

Comment: Qué motor de base de dato estás usando?, si ejecutas solo el query del min que te indica? fijate en éste ejemoplo que hice: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ad364/5 así me funciona.

Comment: estoy utilizando SQL server 2014, voy a probar esa sugerencia, mil gracias, vamos a ver si funciona

Comment: es correcto, hice un par de pruebas usando ese simulador y realiza bien la consulta, con solo un registro en la base de datos o teniendo varios, aun así corrió bien. voy a revisar de nuevo mi codigo a ver si hay algun detalle que estoy pasando por alto. gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Si ese query te funciona entonces el problema esta en los demas where

Comment: ¿Probaste a imprimir `consulta` y probarla directamente en la base de datos?

Comment: Probé hacer la consulta en la pagina del link que me sugeriste pero con la sentencia completa ya no devuelve ningun resultado.

Comment: si solo utilizo la ultima parte del SELECT MIN si devuelve el valor correcto, pero ya con los demás parametros de la consulta no devuelve el resultado, verifiqué que los valores demás valores de la consulta se cumplan por separado y si funciona, solo cuando los uno todos ya no funciona

Comment: Hola Tocayo. Igual y viendo los datos de las tablas. Si nos muestras lo que tiene tiene la tabla Produccion.Transferido. Además de los registros de Transferido.AOI que cumplan con los parametros que usas tal vez se aclare el misterio.

Comment: ok, agragaré algunos de los registros que contiene para que lo puedas ver, pero resulta que haciendo algunas pruebas me di cuente que con ciertos registros si me devuelve la consulta y con otros no lo hace, y he venido revisando los caracteres que conforman la llave primaria, y a pesar de que son iguales en algunos casos no devuelve ningun valor. Las llaves primarias que estoy utilizando tiene la siguiente forma: W001111, W002222, W003333 etc.

Comment: no sé si en los comentarios puedo agregar la table completa, ya que contiene varios registros, habrá alguna otra forma de poder compartirles el codigo?

Comment: ya agregué el codigo completo arriba del procedimiento en su totalidad con una pequeña imagen de la tabla hacia la cual se realiza la consulta.